# Material UI: How can I change the border color of the Select component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to customize the Select component from Material UI.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

However, when the select component is focused, I want to change the border-color from material UI's blue to a custom red color.

I tried setting the styles but it doesn't do anything at all

```
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MuiSelect from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  select: {
    borderColor: '#FF0000',      //<------------ this does nothing
  },
}));

const Select = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel>Months</InputLabel>
      <MuiSelect label="Months" className={classes.select}>
        <MenuItem value="1">January</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="2">February</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="3">March</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="4">April</MenuItem>
      </MuiSelect>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

Select.propTypes = {};

export default Select;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  select: {
    '&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
        borderColor: 'red',
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: I edited the answer because initially I used a `TextField` instead of a `Select`. To work with a `Select`, the nested selector should have no space between `&` and `.Mui-focused`.

Comment: See https://github.com/roninbar/2021-05-26-react-styles/blob/master/src/view/Home/Home.tsx.

Answer (score 9):

If someone is interested in the latest version of MUI 5.

```
import {
  Select,
} from '@mui/material';
import { SxProps } from '@mui/material/styles';
import classes from './component.module.css';

const styles: SxProps = {
  select: {
    '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: '#color',
    },
    '&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: '#color',
      borderWidth: '0.15rem',
    },
  },
};

<Select
     variant="outlined"
     sx={styles.select}
     inputProps={{
       classes: {
         icon: classes.icon,
           },
       }}
  >
```

For the icon, you can create a separate file component.module.css

```
.icon {
    fill: #color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
const selectFieldStyles = {
".MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "#E34824",
    },
        "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "#E34824",
            borderWidth: "thin",
        },
        "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "#E34824",
            borderWidth: "thin",
        },
    };
```

And then in your Select component

```
<Select sx={selectFieldStyles}>...</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Styling the MUI select component

Below I have provided two alternatives.
Both alternatives are valid.
My personal favorite is alternative 2.
Good luck!

#### Alternative 1

```
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';
import * as React from 'react';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import { MenuItem } from '@mui/material';

type SelectInputProps = Readonly<{
  label?: string;
  value?: string;
  onChange?: (event: SelectChangeEvent) => void;
}>;

const SelectInput: React.FC<SelectInputProps> = (props) => {
  const { value = '', label, onChange = () => {} } = props;

  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel
        id="08d1e3b2-5917-4668-9b17-22c49d978fcb"
        sx={{
          '&.MuiInputLabel-root': {
            color: 'orange', // <------------------ label-color by default
          },
          '&.MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused': {
            color: 'green', // <------------------ label-color on focus
          },
        }}
      >
        {label}
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="08d1e3b2-5917-4668-9b17-22c49d978fcb"
        value={value}
        label={label}
        onChange={onChange}
        sx={{
          // ALTERNATIVE 1
          '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
            color: 'purple', // <------------------ arrow-svg-color 
          },
          '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
            borderColor: 'orange', // <------------------ outline-color by default
          },
          '&.MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
            borderColor: 'red', // <------------------ utline-color on hover
          },
          '&.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
            borderColor: 'green', // <------------------ outline-color on focus
          }
        }}
      >
       // PUT YOUR MENU ITEMS HERE
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default SelectInput;
```

#### Alternative 2

```
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';
import * as React from 'react';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import { MenuItem } from '@mui/material';

type SelectInputProps = Readonly<{
  label?: string;
  value?: string;
  onChange?: (event: SelectChangeEvent) => void;
}>;

const SelectInput: React.FC<SelectInputProps> = (props) => {
  const { value = '', label, onChange = () => {} } = props;

  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel
        id="08d1e3b2-5917-4668-9b17-22c49d978fcb"
        sx={{
          '&.MuiInputLabel-root': {
            color: 'orange', // <------------------ label-color by default
          },
          '&.MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused': {
            color: 'green', // <------------------ label-color on focus
          },
        }}
      >
        {label}
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="08d1e3b2-5917-4668-9b17-22c49d978fcb"
        value={value}
        label={label}
        onChange={onChange}
        sx={{
          // ALTERNATIVE 2
          '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
            color: 'purple', // <------------------ arrow-svg-color 
          },
          '&.MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
            '& fieldset': {
              borderColor: 'red', // <------------------ outline-color by default
            },
            '&:hover fieldset': {
              borderColor: 'yellow', // <------------------ outline-color on hover
            },
            '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
              borderColor: 'green', // <------------------ outline-color on focus
            },
          },
        }}
      >
       // PUT YOUR MENU ITEMS HERE
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default SelectInput;
```